# Allow requests to travel up the directory tree (../) in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, webserver

There might be an answer to this, but I don't know how to phrase it properly, so I'll just ask.

I use a module, called [build-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/build-url). It is designed for the browser and provides an easy way to construct URLs with query parameters.

I want to store my website in a folder, called `site` while not having to type it in the URL. I managed to do that easily. However, when the client asks for the `build-url.js` file, he receives a `404`.

Here's how the folder structure looks like:

```
node_modules
    build-url
        dist
            build-url.js

site
    index.html
```

In my code, I have:

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/site"));
```

### The problem

When I go to `http://localhost:5000/`, the `index.html` file is served and everything is fine. Inside, I include the script:

```
<script src="../node_modules/build-url/dist/build-url.js"></script>
```

However, in the browser console, I see:

> GET http://localhost:5000/node_modules/build-url/dist/build-url.js 404 (Not Found)

The server looks for a `node_modules` folder *inside* the `site` folder, instead of going up the directory tree. **How do I fix that?**

Answer (score 0):

It is not a very good idea to allow your web server to send files from outside of the specified folder because it will allow the bad guys to download anything from your server including your confidential data.

You can copy required file to static folder or you can setup *gulp* or any other automation tool to do it automatically.